# Number of real roots of 2n equations on n variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry

There is a map $F: C^n\to R^{2n}$. This map depends on a parameter $t\in [0,\infty)$.  We want to find the number of real roots of $F(z_1, ...,z_n)=0$ for a given $t$. $F$ is a map involving polynomials of $\cos |z_i-z_j|$ and $\frac{1}{\sin^3 |z_i-z_j|}$.  Obviously,   for any $t$, if $(z_1, ...,z_n)$ is a solution, so is the conjugate  $(\bar {z}_1, ...,\bar{z}_n)$. When $t=0$, we know that there is no real solution.

I am studying the number of real solutions to $F=0$ for positive  $t$.   It seems that if one real root appears for some $t>0$, then this root must be a multiple root, and there is some degeneracy occurs.  I do not know what exactly  that degeneracy is. Can you help?

Comment: Is $F$ analytic?  Is there an equation relating $F(\overline{z})$ to $F(z)$?

Comment: I have made the question more precise. Thanks for your interest.